# Running a perl script with root, changing to another user and then back to root?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I've tried to search a lot around the web for this question, to no avail.

Currently I'm building a perl script that needs to do a specific job for each line in some database. The database contains several arguements including a "user" field. 
The script runs as root, and in each line iteration in the db, it will need to switch to the user provided and operate as the user, finishing the round and exiting back to root and then again, running as a different user.

**So far I've tried:**
- using POSIX::setuid($User) in order to switch to the user within the same script, meaning:

```
while (my $line = <$DB>){ 
.. some code ..
POSIX::setuid($User); #switch to user
... do stuff
POSIX::setuid(0); #return to root
```

But this solution didn't work so well, after changing once it was stuck in this user through all iterations of the loop, and couldn't return to root, which is obviously logical because it doesn't have the correct permissions.

Since this didn't work, I thought to myself maybe I should split the job into 2 scripts. One script will run as root, whereas the other script will be called to by root in the first script and then use POSIX::setuid.
I thought, that maybe because it's a subproc\shell it'll just return itself back to root once the job is done on the second script, but it doesn't work as well... I'm kinda out of ideas, anything you guys think'll help?

Comment: Your claim at the bottom that the parent process was affected by the child's call to `setuid` isn't believable.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... could you elaborate on that?

Comment: `setuid` changes the user of a process. It doesn't affect other processes, so the solution you presented at the bottom (create a child to handle the work and call `setuid` in a child) would work. (I don't know enough about this area to know if there are other solutions.)

Comment: And when I run a script within a script, what can I use in order to change the eid\uid of the sub-script only? is there even a way to do that?

Comment: It affects *processes*, not *scripts*. Calling `setuid` in the child process as you mentioned would work (though not necessarily the only or best solution).

Comment: See `$>` in perlvar. To do it without creating a new process, I think you need to swap the UID and EUID, then you can swap them back.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I've tried doing the following in the subscript:

Comment: $> =$User... code... $>=0 seems to work, but the $< stays root throughout the process and thus not really effective for me, because it's still using root's access privileges to check stuff and I need to use the other user's permission.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely not going to work. That's the same as calling `setuid` twice. See `$>` in perlvar. To do it without creating a new process, I think you need to swap the UID and EUID, then you can swap them back.

Comment: Which one do I need to make into the user I wish to use it's priv then? $> or $<? I'm kinda confused. I tried doing: $<=$User; ($<,$>)=($>,$<); ~commands~ ($<,$>)=($>,$<); but it's still using root's privileges. Sorry for all the troubles, but could you explain that please?

Comment: Like I said, that was just a guess. I'm pretty sure there's a way, but I don't know what it is. But at least you know one solution.

Comment: @ikegami for now I chose to just use system to run the second script with system(), hopefully it'll work good

Comment: [Crossposted to PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1209220).